# React how to send object to sub-component when object is held in state of parent component and dynamically updated

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-bootstrap, use-state

home screen of React app

[image]

If I click the edit button next to a row (e.g Jonathan row),  the editor modal comes up **but without the artwork object that I send it through props**.

[image]
My Editor Dialog modal component looks like:

```
export default function EditModal({ config, artwork, show, handleClose, handleSave }) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(artwork.title || '')
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(artwork.price || '')
...

  return (
    <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">
            <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter title" value={title}
              onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}/>
            <Form.Text className="text-muted"></Form.Text>
          </Form.Group>
  ...
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>Price</Form.Label>
            <InputGroup className="mb-3">
              <InputGroup.Text>$</InputGroup.Text>
              <Form.Control aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" value={price}
                onChange={e => setPrice(e.target.value)}/>
            </InputGroup>
          </Form.Group>
...
```

My home page has state set like:

```
export default function Home({ allArtworks, config }) {
  const [showArtworkEditor, setShowArtworkEditor] = useState(false);
  const [artworks, setArtworks] = useState(allArtworks);
  const [artworkToEdit, setArtworkToEdit] = useState({});
```

The home component HTML is:

```
<EditModal config={config} artwork={artworkToEdit} show={showArtworkEditor} handleClose={handleClose} handleSave={handleSave}> </EditModal>
...
<table> ...
<tbody>
  {artworks.map((a,index) => 
    <tr key={index}>
    <td><img height={70} src={config.imageRootURI + '/' + a.imagePath}></img></td>
    <td>{a.title}</td>
    ...
    <td>
      <Button onClick={() => handleEditArtwork(a) }>
         <FaPencilAlt />
       </Button>
    </td>
....


  const handleEditArtwork = async (artwork) => {
    console.log("edit ", artwork);
    setArtworkToEdit(artwork)
    setShowArtworkEditor(true);
  }
```

handleEditArtwork does not set the artworkToEdit state but it does set showArtworkEditor to true.  So the result is the dialog opens but doesn't get the artwork prop

How do I correctly set this up so that I can click the button and have the dialog open with info about the artwork I want to edit?

Answer (score 0):

Add a useEffect hook to the EditModal

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(artwork.title);
    setPrice(artwork.price);
    ...
  }, [artwork])
```

When the artwork prop changes based on button clicks in the home component, this detects it and then runs the function to set new values on the state variables.

This solution with useEffect hook is the modern replacement for a class based approach which is given in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ruOpnXZN6E&t=375s .  It relies on the componentWillReceiveProps method that is being eliminated from React.